# Configurable Product - Simple Product Stock Level

Tags: magento2, cart, configurable-product

I have a selection of configurable products, mainly all color-related. I want to be able to add custom code in the cart showing the stock levels on each child.

The example below has 2 parts added to the cart - one in black which has 9 in stock in the backend and white which has 0 in stock - but when I run the code it shows me 9 for both instances.

How can I get 2 different figures?

[image: The Cart]

Below is a snippet of the code which displays the numbers
[image: Code Snippet]

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module please create this file under **view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- override checkout cart item template -->
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.form">
            <action method="setOverriddenTemplates">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="array">
                    <!-- list override templates -->
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="string">vendor_module::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
                    <item name="simple" xsi:type="string">vendor_module::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
                    <item name="virtual" xsi:type="string">vendor_module::cart/item/default.phtml</item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>


        <referenceBlock class="elastron\elcustom\Block\Cart\Grid" name="checkout.cart.form" template="elastron_elcustom::cart/form.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers" as="renderer.list"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text\ListText" name="checkout.cart.order.actions"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now under **view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml**

```
<?php
$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct();

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product->getId());

$unit=$_product->getData("unit");
$isVisibleProduct = $product->isVisibleInSiteVisibility();
/** @var \Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data $helper */
$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Msrp\Helper\Data');
$canApplyMsrp = $helper->isShowBeforeOrderConfirm($product) && $helper->isMinimalPriceLessMsrp($product);

?>
<tbody class="cart item">
    <tr class="item-info">
        <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Item')) ?>" class="col item">
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl() ?>"
                   title="<?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>"
                   tabindex="-1"
                   class="product-item-photo">
            <?php else:?>
                <span class="product-item-photo">
            <?php endif;?>
            <?= $block->getImage($block->getProductForThumbnail(), 'cart_page_product_thumbnail')->toHtml() ?>
            <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                </a>
            <?php else: ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="product-item-details">
                <strong class="product-item-name">
                    <?php if ($block->hasProductUrl()):?>
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl() ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?></a>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getProductName()) ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </strong>
                <?= "YOUR MESSAGE HERE" ?>
                <?php if ($_options = $block->getOptionList()):?>
                    <dl class="item-options">
                        <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
                            <?php $_formatedOptionValue = $block->getFormatedOptionValue($_option) ?>
                            <dt><?= __($block->escapeHtml($_option['label'])) ?></dt>
                            <dd>
                                <?php if (isset($_formatedOptionValue['full_view'])): ?>
                                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_formatedOptionValue['full_view'] ?>
                                <?php else: ?>
                                    <?= __($block->escapeHtml($_formatedOptionValue['value'], ['span'])) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </dd>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </dl>
                <?php endif;?>
                <?php if ($messages = $block->getMessages()): ?>
                    <?php foreach ($messages as $message): ?>                        
                        <div class="cart item message <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $message['type'] ?>"><div><?= $block->escapeHtml($message['text']) ?></div></div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $addInfoBlock = $block->getProductAdditionalInformationBlock(); ?>
                <?php if ($addInfoBlock): ?>
                    <?= $addInfoBlock->setItem($_item)->toHtml() ?>
                <?php endif;?>
            </div>
        </td>

        <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
            <td class="col msrp" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>">
                <span class="pricing msrp">
                    <span class="msrp notice"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('See price before order confirmation.') ?></span>
                    <?php $helpLinkId = 'cart-msrp-help-' . $_item->getId(); ?>
                    <a href="#" class="action help map" id="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ ($helpLinkId) ?>" data-mage-init='{"addToCart":{"helpLinkId": "#<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $helpLinkId ?>","productName": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $product->getName() ?>","showAddToCart": false}}'>
                        <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __("What's this?") ?></span>
                    </a>
                </span>
            </td>
        <?php else: ?>
            <td class="col price" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Price')) ?>">
                <?= $block->getUnitPriceHtml($_item) ?>
            </td>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <td class="col qty" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty'))  ?>">
            <div class="field qty">
                <div class="control qty">
                    <label for="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty">
                        <span class="label"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Qty') ?></span>
                        <input id="cart-<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>-qty"
                               name="cart[<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_item->getId() ?>][qty]"
                               data-cart-item-id="<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>"
                               value="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getQty() ?>"
                               type="number"
                               size="5"
                               title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?>"
                               class="input-text qty"
                               data-validate="{required:true,'validate-greater-than-zero':true}"
                               data-role="cart-item-qty"/>
                    </label>
                    <div ><?= $unit ?></div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="col subtotal" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Subtotal')) ?>">
            <?php if ($canApplyMsrp): ?>
                <span class="cart msrp subtotal">--</span>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?= $block->getRowTotalHtml($_item) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="item-actions">
        <td colspan="4">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getActions($_item) ?>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

If this solved your issue please don't forget to up vote / mark as answered. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

While this generates a message on the cart, the goal is to make it so if a child product of the configurable product has 0 stock a message appears stating we have no stock, that is the main goal, so I am trying to work out how to extract the simple product QTY from the configurable one